# D3.js - formating Number - throws error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using `angularjs` for developing my app. and i am integrated a graph from `d3.js`, i am getting a number from json and that need to convert in to money and shown in the center of the graph.

i tried like this for a sample:

```
var text = group.selectAll("text.title")
            .data(data)
            .enter();

text.append("text")
    .classed("title-total", true )
    .text( function (d, i) {
    if( catg === "payStTotalGraph" )
            var format = d3.format("00,000,0000");
            console.log ( format(123456)); //output as 123,456 instead of 12,356
            return d[i].value;

})
.attr("text-anchor","middle")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + 20 + ")");
```

and Angular throw the error as :

```
TypeError: format is not a function
    at SVGTextElement.<anonymous> (dirProjectSummary.js:328)
    at SVGTextElement._a.text.arguments.length.each.function.n.textContent (d3.min.js:3)
    at d3.min.js:3
    at Y (d3.min.js:1)
    at Array._a.each (d3.min.js:3)
    at Array._a.text (d3.min.js:3)
    at drawPaymentGraph (dirProjectSummary.js:324)
    at dirProjectSummary.js:262
    at Object.m [as forEach] (angular.js:350)
    at Object.<anonymous> (dirProjectSummary.js:250)
```

What is the correct way to format the numbers in d3js in the angular?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is error is with d3 so will be better to remove angularjs flag. D3 formatting format in https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting also it will be better to provide splunk/jsbin to help other investigate your issue.

Comment: But i am getting output here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has absolutely nothing to do with Angular.
The problem is not using `{` and `}` in your `if` statement. The correct code would be (at least I suppose):

```
text.append("text")
    .classed("title-total", true )
    .text( function (d, i) {
    if( catg === "payStTotalGraph" ) { // <- opening
            var format = d3.format("00,000,0000");
            console.log ( format(123456)); //output as 123,456 instead of 12,356
            return d[i].value;
    } // <-- closing
})
```

I think this small part of your program is not finished yet, because you're using the format-function only in `console.log`. But the missing curly braces are the reason for the `TypeError`.

In case you don't know: JavaScript doesn't have block-scope and variables are hoisted. There are many articles about JavaScript scope and hoisting on the web.